Oracle - Tagging records to be processed latter
I have a spring boot service which picks up and processes records in batches from a table. It uses below approach while doing so -

Generates nextval of a DB sequence.
Updates this DB sequence into a column of look up table using SQL in below format

UPDATE LOOKUP_TABLE SET LOOKUP_KEY = <<seq generated in step1>> WHERE LOOKUPDT BETWEEN :startDt AND :endDt AND ROWNUM <= :rownum;

where rownum is the batch size (say 1000).

This seems to be working fine most of the time but occasionally I am seeing below behaviour -
Even though there are less than 1000 records at a particular point in time, I could see records getting processed in 2 diff batches. For eg: There were 571 candidate records to be processed. Since 571 < batch size, all of these should have got processed in one batch but 570 were processed together while 1 was processed alone in next run. The value of the LOOKUPDT column of this 1 anomaly record and the last record of 570 batch is exactly the same.
Not sure if this is the correct way to apply rownum with an update stmt which may be causing this behaviour? Please advise.
